Code Signing in ElectronJS on Mac with Electron Forge: Can't get it to sign correctly
I am having the darnedest time trying to sign and notarize my code on Mac. Here is my forge.config.js section:
osxSign: {
   identity: settings.osx.identity,
   'hardened-runtime': true,
   entitlements: 'path/to/my/entitlements.mac.plist',
   'entitlements-inherit': 'path/to/my/entitlements.mac.plist',
   'signature-flags': 'library',
   'gatekeeper-assess': false,
   verbose: true,
},
   osxNotarize: {
   appleId: 'myappleid',
   appleIdPassword: 'myapppassword',
},

And here are the errors I get every time (de-identifying my app info):
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Failed to codesign your application with code: 1

This.app: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present


Executable=/private/var/folders/sj/p_n_wbks78zdx527rwz2phy80000gn/T/electron-packager/tmp-JAFWup/This.app/Contents/MacOS/This
Identifier=Electron
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20400 size=513 flags=0x20002(adhoc,linker-signed) hashes=13+0 location=embedded
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=720896
VersionSDK=917504
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=d136a9abe9f7090c820f97f1fd2ae1f620a0ad21
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=d136a9abe9f7090c820f97f1fd2ae1f620a0ad21686bdc97802a27e49c9741b1
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=d136a9abe9f7090c820f97f1fd2ae1f620a0ad21686bdc97802a27e49c9741b1
CMSDigestType=2
Executable Segment base=0
Executable Segment limit=16384
Executable Segment flags=0x1
Page size=4096
CDHash=d136a9abe9f7090c820f97f1fd2ae1f620a0ad21
Signature=adhoc
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements=none
at /Users/myname/.../node_modules/@electron/notarize/lib/check-signature.js:74:19
   at Generator.next (\<anonymous\>)
   at fulfilled (/Users/myname/.../node_modules/@electron/notarize/lib/check-signature.js:28:58)
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Does anyone have any ideas/experience here?
I've tried different configuration in Electron Forge (including adding folders to extraResource), I've tried running xcrun commands, I've tried slightly different certificates (though that shouldn't be the problem here), and nothing seems to work. I just need to sign and notarize code for distribution. Could be entitlements, but I just got some default content for that... don't know much about that though.

Did you ever find a solution to this issue?
